# Force Razor syntax literals

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I had this in a .cshtml view:

```
    <script src="/Scripts/app/app.min.js?@Html.BuildTag()"></script>
```

Razor renders this to the view:

```
    <script src="/Scripts/app/app.min.js?41231112"></script>
```

When I change the .cshtml view to this:

```
    <script src="/Scripts/app/app.min.js@Html.BuildTag()"></script>
```

Then I get this in the rendered view:

```
    <script src="/Scripts/app/app.min.js@Html.BuildTag()"></script>
```

How do I get `@Html.BuildTag()` to render `41231112` when there's no leading `?` character?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make it an explicit code block by wrapping it in `()`.

```
<script src="/Scripts/app/app.min.js@(Html.BuildTag())"></script>
```